# Neo4j - Distributing

Tags: architecture, neo4j

I am developing a new application.
The underlying data is topological in nature.
The application should support multi tenancy and be ready to handle large graph for each of its tenants. I have roughly the following two options: (1) Use a NoSQL DB like HBase and implement the graph abstraction layer by myself (2) Use Neo4j.

To reach a decision I need to understand Neo4j architecture:
1) Are queries being run in memory or in disk? If the answer is in memory - does Neo4j loads the entire graph into memory or does it implement some caching strategy?
2) How does it scale? Can Neo4j run in a distributed mode? If so, how is the data set being partitioned? Is it an arbitrary partition or is it a topological partition?

Thanks,
Uri

Answer (score 0):

1) queries run in memory (mmio from disk, and object cache), see:
http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/configuration-caches.html
2) no distributed mode yet. you can scale horizontally somewhat by distributing the cache:
http://jim.webber.name/2011/02/scaling-neo4j-with-cache-sharding-and-neo4j-ha/

Comment: Nice link @wesFreeman. But your second link was broken. Here is the correct link I guess http://jimwebber.org/2011/02/scaling-neo4j-with-cache-sharding-and-neo4j-ha/


Just to add up on the answer as Wes already said, to handle traversing large databases quickly, neo4j takes the help of its high-availability model. If you have 3-4 machines placed in a network stack or placed geographically, you try to access the data where its likely been cached. That way the chances are more to hit the sweet spot and queries will be faster. Read the article for more info. :)